# Convert Timestamp into days hours mins ago

Tags: php

How to convert Timestamp into days hours mins ago ?

E.g I have a Timestamp : 2014-02-27 09:37:20

How to convert this timestamp into 4 day, 2 hours ,20mins ago ?

Comment: Please remember to Google first before asking a question. A query for `Convert Timestamp into days hours mins ago` would have given you plenty of existing duplicates.

Comment: Try out this video tutorial on it:
http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=725

Answer (score 0):

You should be better of with the [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/datetime.createfromformat)

```
<?php
$dt='2014-02-27 09:37:20';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dt);
$currdt=new DateTime();
$currdt->diff($date);
echo $currdt->format('d')." days ".$currdt->format('H')." hours ".$currdt->format('i')." mins ago";
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
04 days 05 hours 31 mins ago
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/109244)

Comment: I guess not working fine : https://eval.in/109270

Comment: 4 days 5 hours and 31 minutes ago is not 2/27/14 9:37:20am Would timezone affect it?

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you're looking for?

```
// built with php5

// set system default time zone 
$timeZone = 'UTC';
date_default_timezone_set($timeZone); 

// find the difference
$interval = date_diff(date_create('2014-02-27 09:37:20'), date_create());
$out = $interval->format("Days:%d,Hours:%H,Minutes:%i");
print_r($out);
```

For the list of available time zone string you may find here
http://www.date-default-timezone-set.com/

Comment: Showing wrong time , Try this input : 2014-03-04 10:40:20

Comment: I think it's due to the timezone setting. I've modified the code and you may give a try.